# Java - Using Class as pseudodatabase

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I try to build a project using the MVC model and using a class named "StaticDB" as a pseudodatabase. Let's say for example I want to build the login feature. The flow will be like:

1. User clicks login button so it triggers a method (**InterfaceLogin class**):

   ```
   private void loginBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
   String u = usernameF.getText();
   String p = passwordF.getText();
   Controller.logintest(u,p);
   }
   ```
2. Now the **Controller** class will run the logintest() method to check if the credentials are correct. In fact what the login method should do is check the returned value of another method in **User** class that checks the "mock database" if there is a user with an exact password. If the returned value is 1 there is else an error message is displayed.

There are a few problems with this method. First of all I can't think of a good way to make the StaticDB class. I tried a few things but most of the time I face a non-static can't be refferenced method error... Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an off-the-shelf in-memory database?

Comment: Yes it's a requirement for the project.

Comment: Why is your database class static?

Comment: It's not an actual database, just for testing puproses

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well firstly since your database holds your application's business data, you'd need to have it stored in the `Model`.

```
public class Model {
    /* Member Variables. */
    private final Database mDatabase = new Database();
}
```

When your `Controller` handles the `MouseEvent`, it can parse the data and delegate this over to the `Model`, which is receives upon instantiation. The architecture would result in an approach along the lines of:

```
this.getModel().getDatabase().onHandleLogin(pUserName, pPassword);
```

The implementation of the `onHandleLogin` method in the database would allow you to manipulate it's member variables, without requiring the `Controller` to understand any of the actual implementation details of the `Database`.

If your hands are tied and the database has to be`static`, you could forego encapsulation within the `Model` completely, though this would deviate from the MVC paradigm.

If the Database was static, you'd have something like the following:

```
public class Database {

    private static final List<Credentials> LIST_CREDENTIALS = new ArrayList<Credentials>();

    static {
        /* Here we could initialize the LIST_CREDENTIALS when the Database is first loaded into memory. I.e. populate it with some example users. */
    }

    public static final void onHandleLogin(final String pUsername, final String pPassword) {
        /* Iterate the LIST_CREDENTIALS and check whether the user exists. Since the List is static, we can reference it from a static method. */
    }

}
```

Comment: Instances of the model get stored in the database, not the other way around.

Comment: I've not yet come across that approach. Is that application dependent? I figured the MVC uses one core Model to represent the application in it's entirety. Would your approach instead mean you use a database which persists segments of the whole application?

Comment: MVC has core models, instances of which are persisted in a data store (e.g. a database). My Java MVC web apps have controller, service, and DAO layers (I use Spring so these are annotated `@Controller`, `@Service`, and `@Repository` respectively).  Models tend to be for the most part Java beans (though we frequently use `Map<String, Object>` in my current project) and have no knowledge of their environment...they just carry data around.